# Alcohol Nonmeclature - Organic Chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

I'm new to organic chemistry and having some trouble naming alcohols. I came across this molecule, I believe it's name is 3-ethyl 2-pentanol, but my online checker system is saying that I am wrong. Am I wrong, or is the online checker looking for 3-ethyl pentan-2-ol?
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No space between substituents and parent name. 3-ethylpentan-2-ol

Comment: 3-Ethyl-2-pentanol is a accepted IUPAC name. However, preffered IUPAC name (PIN) is 3-ethylpentan-2-ol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_IUPAC_name).